# Shell script to find folder

Tags: bash, shell

I have few randoms date folders on location `/Users/skull/Desktop` 
and I want to select/find the folder of today's date and if not there then select less nearest to todays date. Should not take high date folder
eg: Today date `2016-09-08` as on location we don’t have `2016-09-08` folder so it should take less nearest date which is `2016-09-06` or if `2016-09-06` not there then `2016-08-30`

Folder names:

```
2016-07-015
2016-07-27
2016-08-30
2016-09-05
2016-09-06
2016-09-10
2016-09-15
2016-09-20
```

Code I have so far:

```
location=/Users/Skull/Desktop
DAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d"| awk '{print $1$2$3}')
#2016-09-08
DATA_FOLDER=
```

Comment: `ls | tail -n 1` will bring you todays dir or the latest (nearest), if you don't have future dates in dir names.

Comment: @JamesBrown Look at the example, he has some future dates.

Comment: @Skull What is `| awk '{print $1$2$3}'` supposed to achieve?!

Comment: Do you *have* to write it in bash? If Zsh is also an option, you could get it easily by `DATA_FOLDER=$location/2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9](N[-1])`. The wildcard pattern expands to those directory entries which look like a date (more or less), and the list is implicitly sorted. The -1 picks the last element, and the N suppresses an error message if there are no matching directory entries (`DATA_FOLDER` will then be empty).

Comment: @James Brown if i am using   ( ls | tail -n 1 ) then i am getting result of 2016-09-20 and today's date 2016-09-09 and if this folder is not there it should select last nearest date folder which is 2016-09-06

Comment: @Biffen its not impotent to use  awk as (date +"%Y-%m-%d") giving me same result 
    | awk '{print $1$2$3}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output the names in reverse order. Then use an `awk` script that prints the first one that's less than or equal to the current date.

```
DATA_FOLDER=$(ls -r "$location" | awk -v day=$DAY '$0 <= day {print; exit}')
```

Comment: In my environment (Debian) `ls -R` is `--recursive` and `-r` is `--reverse`.

Comment: @Barmar The result is coming 2016-07-27 i think its telling the oldest folder and i want the current date or lest nearest to current date.

`location="/Users/skull/Desktop/folders/" 
echo $location

DAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d"| awk '{print $1$2$3}')

#2016-09-09

DATA_FOLDER=$(ls -R "$location" | awk -v day=$DAY '$0 <= day {print; exit}')

echo "$DATA_FOLDER" `

Comment: @Barmar @James Brown Thank you i have used `DATA_FOLDER=$(ls -r "$location" | awk -v day=$DAY '$0 <= day {print; exit}')` and i am getting the current date folder and if not then lest near which is 2016-09-06 :) Thank you once again for you help guys.

Comment: @skull don't forget to accept his answer, ie. tick his tick.

Answer (score 1):

Never parse `ls` output : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Better use `printf` and `awk`:

```
cd "$location"
printf '%q\n' * | awk 'END{if(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/){print}}'
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' * | ` is exactly equivalent to `ls -1 | `.

Comment: @Gilles Quenot @alvits By using your `DATA_FOLDER=$(printf '%s\n' | awk 'END{if(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/){print}}')` or `DATA_FOLDER=$(ls -1| awk 'END{if(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/){print}}')` i am getting the result 2016-09-20 which is the highest date folder in location, I have change the days and added 2016-10-29 and then result is 2016-10-29. As it should show current date folder and if not there in location then less nearest date which is 2016-09-06

Comment: @alvits No it isn't.  `ls` does all kinds of wacky things with unprintable characters, directories, etc.

Comment: You used `%s`. If you used `%q` I would agree with you that it's not the same as `ls -1`. Did you even test your code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar @James Brown which helped. Below is the final working script of my qus :)

```
location=/Users/Skull/Desktop
DAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
#today date = 2016-09-09
DATA_FOLDER=$(ls -r "$location" | awk -v day=$DAY '$0 <= day {print; exit}')
echo "$DATA_FOLDER"
#Result = 2016-09-06
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like that:

```
DATA_FOLDER="$(ls "$location" | grep -P '^\d{4}-d{2}-d{2}$' | sed "/^$(date +%F)\$/q" | tail -n1)"
```

I use ls to find all the files, filter only the ones whose name is a date, the keep the ones up to the one that corresponds to today's date, and finally discard all but the last one, which has to be today's date or the the most recent date.